# Appending data to SSIS flexible file storage

Tags: ssis

[SSIS] Do we have any settings for SSIS Flexible file destination to support "Append" data for Apache Parquet file? I am writing my data to the file in a loop and looks like every time it is writing, it is overwriting the existing data. Appreciate any help. Thanks

Writing data in loop. Expecting data to be appended, but getting overwritten

Answer (score 0):

The [Flexible File Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/flexible-file-task?view=sql-server-ver16) is the Azure equivalent of the File System Task which is involved with copying/deleting files and folders.

The [Flexible File Destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/flexible-file-destination?view=sql-server-ver16) is the sink for writing parquet files. Based on this MSDN question from 2 years ago citing that Append was a requested feature going on for 4 years

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/226219/flexible-file-destination-enable-appending-data-mo